# Heroku Deployed App, Page Refresh error or Redirecting error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, react-router, react-router-dom

I've successfully deployed MERN App on Heroku, it is working fine on case when i don't refresh the page. if i refresh the page it gives and error of **Internal Server Error**
Your can review the application here as an example https://arcane-taiga-53185.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Add the server side code

Comment: **this is the code where nodejs called front-end pages**

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    req.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}


**ReactJs routing**

  <Route path="/about-us" component={AboutUs} />
  <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />

Comment: routing is working properly, when I refresh the page it gives an error of **Internal Server Error**

Comment: What you're getting in logs? You can check logs in heroku with command `heroku logs`

Comment: 2020-04-10T15:31:23.338541+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /undefined 500 148 - 0.712 ms
2020-04-10T15:31:23.339125+00:00 app[web.1]: **TypeError: req.sendFile is not a function**

Comment: As mentioned in log, change req.sendFile to res.sendFile

Comment: Thanks it was great help. it is working now.