# Getting Error when refreshing my react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, routes, endpoint

My app is working fine until i try to referesh the page. I made the build version of the frontend and then pasted all the contents in the public folder of node js backend. Everything is working just fine until i do a refresh.
I find a similar problem : [Heroku Deployed App, Page Refresh error or Redirecting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142305/heroku-deployed-app-page-refresh-error-or-redirecting-error)

The only difference is i am getting this error:  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

I did heroku logs and found this:

> 2021-01-29T20:31:35.136038+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /posts/myNewsFeed 304
> 377.308 ms - - 2021-01-29T20:31:35.137763+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/posts/myNewsFeed"
> host=insta-clone-01.herokuapp.com
> request_id=d0dfee79-74f4-43c2-9ce5-7df121136872 fwd="1.38.45.193"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=383ms status=304 bytes=181
> protocol=https
>
> 2021-01-29T20:31:37.519726+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/home" host=insta-clone-01.herokuapp.com
> request_id=d0a7784f-bcbe-41ed-88de-43e71cd364c7 fwd="1.38.45.193"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=https
> 2021-01-29T20:31:37.520005+00:00 app[web.1]: GET /home 404 1.326 ms -
> 160

These are the logs for the same page but the first is when i normally get to the page and the second one is when i refresh the page.

what i can say from this is when i am normally trying to get to a page the request is happening to the /posts/myNewsFeed which is my node api endpoint but when i am refreshing the same page the request is happening to /home which is my route for the page ,not the node api endpoint and that's why i am getting the error.

You can see the project here https://github.com/Aditya-shrivastav/InstagramClone

Anyone who can give a solution for this?